# What is slowing my application?

Tags: iis-7, asp.net, performance

I am generating a report as a web page 3MB,

I am a newbie, I am not sure why it is slow:

1. the size is big
2. the upload internet is slow
3. the server is slow
4. the browser is taking  long time to process the client code (Jquery, javascript)

If you need more information please ask them as comments so I can answer them.

I have a quad CPU, 4G Ram with two web application running, the (Down/UP) is 8Mb/3Mb as ISP says, speedtest.net shows only: Ping 41ms, Download 4Mb, up: 0.16Mb

Comment: all the CSS + JS files = 156KB , it is the report content, or??

Answer (score 1):

Firebug in Firefox (F12) or Chrome's Developer Tools (Ctrl+Shift+J) can show you which phase of processing the request/response took how much time. (Download, CSS processing, JS evaluating, etc.) IE made some tiny progress when it comes to web-development tools, I'm not sure it goes that much into detail though.
(I'm sorry, I'm not allowed to respond directly to your comments.)
Depends on what you call 'slow'. But CSS+JS having 156kB is nothing that should make the page extremely slow. (It is kinda big chunk of code, but like I said, still far from being overkill.)

Comment: ^^^ read above (edited)... If you have the page accessible somewhere I might try to take a look.

Comment: How to install and use Firebug at a basic level. http://fosscasts.com/screencasts/25-The-Firebug-Firefox-extension